# Nested Manipulate in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Please consider:

```
Function[subID, 
         pointSO[subID] = RandomInteger[{1, 4}, {5, 2}]] /@ {"subA", "subB"};

Manipulate[
           Manipulate[
                      Graphics[{
                                Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {5, 5}],
                                White,Point@pointSO[subID][[i]]
                               },
                               ImageSize -> {400, 300}], 
           {i,Range[Length@pointSO[subID]]}], 
{subID, {"subA", "subB"}}]
```

[image]

Provided that `pointSO[subID]` actually yields to lists of different length, is there a way to avoid having 2 `Manipulate` given that one of the manipulated variable depends on the other?

Comment: As is, both lists are of the same length. Perhaps using `listlength["subA"] = 5; listlength["subB"] = 9;
Function[subID, 
   pointSO[subID] = 
    RandomInteger[{1, 4}, {listlength[subID], 2}]] /@ {"subA", 
   "subB"};` illustrates the issue that arises with single Manipulate.

Comment: My solution works fine with lists of differing length. The manipulator for i adjusts dynamically. I think the main porblem may be from not specifying a default value for i.

Comment: ... You need to explicitly set `ControlType -> SetterBar`in the inner Manipulate to avoid different controls in the inner Manipulate for `subA` and `subB`.

Comment: @Timo, you get the dreaded red rectangle when you switch from `subB` to `subA` when the value of `i` is gretaer than the length of the list `subA` where the two lists `subA` and `subB` have lengths, say 5 and 9.

Comment: I see. That may be unavoidable, I can't off the top of my head think of ways to fool Manipulate into refreshing the second control when switching the first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am *not* sure that I got exactly what you are asking for, but I figured what you want is something like the following:

Given a UI with one variable, say an array that can change in size, and another (dependent) variable, which represents say an index into the current array that you want to use from the UI to index into the array.

But you do not want to fix the index variable layout in the UI, since it depends, at run time, on the size of the array, which can change using the second variable.

Here is a one manipulate, which has a UI that has an index control variable, which updates dynamically on the UI as the size of the array changes.

I used SetterBar for the index (the dependent variable) but you can use slider just as well. SetterBar made it more clear on the UI what is changing.

When you change the length of the array, the index control variable automatically updates its maximum allowed index to be used to match the current length of the array.

When you shrink the array, the index will also shrink.

I am not sure if this is what you want, but if it, you can adjust this approach to fit into your problem

```
Manipulate[

 Grid[{
   {Style[Row[{"data[[", i, "]]=", data[[i]]}], 12]},
   {MatrixForm[data], SpanFromLeft}
   },
  Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {0, 1}
  ],

 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {Text["select index into the array = "],
     SetterBar[Dynamic[i, {i = #} &], Range[1, Length[data]], 
      ImageSize -> Tiny,
      ContinuousAction -> False]
     },

    {
     Text["select how long an array to build = "],
     Manipulator[
      Dynamic[n, {n = #; If[i > n, i = n]; 
         data = Table[RandomReal[], {n}]} &],
      {1, 10, 1}, ImageSize -> Tiny, ContinuousAction -> False]
     , Text[Length[data]], SpanFromLeft
     }
    }, Alignment -> Left
   ],

 {{n, 2}, None},
 {{i, 2}, None},
 {{data, Table[RandomReal[], {2}]}, None},
 TrackedSymbols -> {n, i}
 ]
```

[image]

[image]

**update 8:30 PM**
fyi, just made a fix to the code above to add a needed extra logic.

Comment: Dunno if this is what the OP wanted or not, but it's useful to me! :D

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the problem of `i` being too large when switching lists, you could add an `If[]` statement at the beginning of the `Manipulate`, e.g.

```
Clear[pointSO];
MapThread[(pointSO[#] = RandomInteger[{1, 4}, {#2, 2}]) &, 
  {{"subA", "subB"}, {5, 7}}];

Manipulate[
 If[i > Length[pointSO[subID]], i = Length[pointSO[subID]]];
 Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {5, 5}], White, 
   Point@pointSO[subID][[i]]}, ImageSize -> {400, 300}],
 {{subID, "subA"}, {"subA", "subB"}, SetterBar},
 {{i, {}}, Range[Length@pointSO[subID]], SetterBar}]
```

Maybe nicer is to reset `i` when switching between lists. This can be done by doing something like

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {5, 5}], White, 
   Point@pointSO[subID][[i]]}, ImageSize -> {400, 300}],
 {{subID, "subA"}, 
   SetterBar[Dynamic[subID, (i = {}; subID = #) &], {"subA", "subB"}] &},
 {{i, {}}, Range[Length@pointSO[subID]], SetterBar}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative implementation that preserves selection settings for each data set:

```
listlength["subA"] = 5; listlength["subB"] = 9; 
Function[subID, 
pointSO[subID] = 
RandomInteger[{1, 4}, {listlength[subID], 2}]] /@ {"subA", "subB"};

Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {5, 5}], 
 Dynamic[If[subID == "subA", Yellow, Cyan]], PointSize -> .05, 
 Dynamic@Point@pointSO[subID][[k]]}, ImageSize -> {400, 300}], 
Row[{Panel[
SetterBar[
Dynamic[subID, 
(subID = #; k = If[subID == "subA", j, i]) &],{"subA", "subB"}, 
 Appearance -> "Button", Background -> GrayLevel[.8]]], "      ", 
PaneSelector[{"subA" -> 
  Dynamic@Panel[
    SetterBar[Dynamic[j, (k = j; j = #) &], 
     Range[Length@pointSO["subA"]], Appearance -> "Button", 
     Background -> Yellow]], 
 "subB" -> 
  Dynamic@Panel[
    SetterBar[Dynamic[i, (k = i; i = #) &], 
     Range[Length@pointSO["subB"]], Appearance -> "Button", 
     Background -> Cyan]]}, Dynamic[subID]]}]]
```

Output examples:

[image: data set subB]

[image: data set subA]